# SwiftUI updating state of variable issue. NavigationStack won't present next view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have simple `Login` module which I would like to use with my back4app service which uses `Parse` functionality. The idea is to show next screen `HomeView` when `$loginViewModel.isValid` is `true`. But the app does not present `HomeView` in `NavigationStack`

I have `LoginView` with next code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Parse

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("username", text: $loginViewModel.username)
                TextField("password", text: $loginViewModel.password)
                Button(action: {
                    loginViewModel.login()
                }) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .onAppear() {
                let applicationId = "id goes here"
                let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
                    $0.applicationId = applicationId
                    $0.clientKey = "key goes here"
                    $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
                }
                Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Login")
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $loginViewModel.isValid) {
                HomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `LoginViewModel` class:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Published properties that the view can bind to
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    
    var loginService = LoginService()

    func login() {
        loginService.username = username
        loginService.password = password
        loginService.isValid = isValid
        
        loginService.loginUser()
    }
}
```

The `LoginService` class:

```
class LoginService: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    
    func loginUser() {
        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: username, password: password) { (pfUser, error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isValid = false
                }
            } else {
                guard let unwrappedPFUser = pfUser else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isValid = false
                    }
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isValid = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note you should be using `@StateObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()`
 and it is best **not to nest** ObservableObjects. Change to `struct LoginService{...}`.
 Note you don't change your LoginViewModel `isValid = true` anywhere in your code.
 You change the `LoginService` isValid, but that is not what you use
 in `.navigationDestination(...)`. My suggestion is to restructure your code and use only one
 `ObservableObject` model.

Comment: hey nice nick name=) thanks for the comment, I supposed as used `isPresented: $loginViewModel.isValid` I created kind of binding, but yea I got your point as func `func login()` does not bind anything it's kind of separated objects, yea I agree that creating `ObservableObject` model is the best way to do it and yea thanks agree that LoginService is overloaded with unneeded things from swift ui doing the job not related to it directly

Comment: It is a matter of Observing You have to observe LoginService too in your current setup. But just FYI `ObservableObject` is meant for updating a `View` it has no business in the service layer. You should be using Combine or any other way of notifying the presentation layer of a change. I would use `CurrentValueSubject` instead of `Published` in the Service